# Regex to get each characters between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

```
apple man <span field="apply to|1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln|Data" contenteditable="false"> open the door.
```

Here i want to get the field properties separated like `'apply to', '1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln', 'data'` and add it to another tag like `<data="apply to" value="1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln'">`

This is the regex i'm using now `<span\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?field="([^"]*)"\scontenteditable="([^"]*)">` it gives a output Group 1 as `apply to|1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln|Data`

Comment: I guess it could be something like `<span\s+field="([\w\s]+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)`: https://regex101.com/r/LC7ypc/1, at least something to start with.

Comment: In this regex it's not taking if there are any characters like '$%#@'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just split the resulting group:

```
var str = "apply to|1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln|Data";
var res = str.split("|");

console.log(res);
// Array [ "apply to", "1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln", "Data" ]
```

or...

```
var res = group1.split("|");
```

Then do whatever you want with it.

So regex might look like this:

```
const regex = /<span\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?field="([^"]*)"\scontenteditable="([^"]*)">/g;
const tag = `apple man <span field="apply to|1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln|Data" contenteditable="false"> open the door.`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(tag)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        if (groupIndex == 1) {
          var res = match.split("|");
          console.log(`<data="${res[0]}" value="${res[1]}">`);
        }
    });
}
```

**Result**:

```
<data="apply to" value="1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln">
```

**Demo**:

https://jsfiddle.net/pheqfkwb/

Comment: how to replace those tags by using these